# How to give a hyperlink to a https website in HTML?

Tags: html, web

I have tried to give a hyperlink to a https website from my html form. But, it redirects me to the http link of the same domain. Is there any constraint in linking the https website in the html form's href?

Comment: Why not show the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If you are being redirected, then it is a decision made on the server you are making the HTTPS request to.

Comment: I have configured 2 different websites in that the only difference is made by the protocol. I can understand your answer. But, when i manually entered the URL, the 2 websites are differentiated based on the http and https.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, It works like this -
    [redirect](https://www.facebook.com)

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">redirect</a>
```

Comment: If you give http instead of https, the result will be same